# Are the end velocities of masses (falling from infinity to earth) with equal $\rho$ and arbitrary form , scale independent?

Tags: gravity, friction, drag

Yesterday I asked a question I didn't intend to ask. Of course, masses with different forms (and equal $\rho$) do not reach the same end velocity when falling on earth from infinity.
What I meant to ask was if we have a mass with an arbitrary form and another one with the same form (and mass density), but with all spatial dimensions scaled up or down, will the end velocity of the masses be the same when reaching earth?

So for example, will a uniform metal ball reach earth with the same velocity as the "same" ball with a different radius?

Comment: I get the feeling you would run into problems if the scale between the two were fairly large.  AFAIK drag doesn't actually scale linearly with area (basing this off the fact that you can't just expect to make a 1:10 scale replica in a wind tunnel and be able to scale results linearly).

Comment: No, taking an extreme example, a soccer ball would not arrive at Earth with the same velocity as a large planet, obviously  mutual gravity effects would need to be taken into account. I wonder have I read your question properly, it's easy enough to work out for  what incoming mass the Earth will be deflected from its orbit.